# I want to convert ppt files to pdf in php?

Tags: php, powerpoint

actually i have to display ppt file in browser but it gives download option instead of displaying.so im using it to convert in pdf format so that browser display it and restrict user to download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you use Google Docs or HTML5 presentation systems
Read more here
http://www.sitepoint.com/5-free-html5-presentation-systems/

Answer (score 0):

you may alternatively try saving the ppt as image by `File - Save as - Save as type` and show the image in your browser.

**NB**: You can't restrict the user from downloading. Alternatively, you can show images to registered users.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict users from downloading if you will use flash player with external datasource like non-cacheable stream video. PDF and images can be freely downloaded even if you put it in "iframe", block the "mouseclick" and "drag-and-drop" events. By the way, if you can see it in a browser, then you already have copy of it in the system cache.
Sorry.